# Unable to install .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-server-2008, windows-installer

I have cleaned up the .net frame work 4.0 from my system using clean utility. It was uninstalled .net frame work framework 4.0. Then i tried to reinstall 4.0 using the set up file got from below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx

But i am getting installation failed error.

Error msg : Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation.

I am using windows server 2008 32bit OS.

Can any one please give me a solution?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you already have a .NET installation on your system but it's corrupted.
If this is the case you can try the following:

Go to `Control Panel->Programs and Features` and open the `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` installer.

Select `Repair .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to its original state`. Reboot afterwards.

After this is done try to reinstall .NET Framework 4 using the offline installer

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718

Comment: I have uninstalled .net framework 4.0 client profile using cleanup utility.

Comment: Was this a Microsoft supported cleanup utility? Or a crazy third party one? If it wasn't from Microsoft, time to re-install your OS.